# The correlation between a leaf's age and its length in the initial stage of growth

Tags: botany, homework, growth

I am building a machine learning algorithm which predicts the age of a leaf before its maturity period based on its measured length or area. I would like to know whether there is a mathematical relation to describe this or a repository of data on this topic.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Please narrow it down to a specific issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. Moreover, we expect you to show some research from your part.